# iTunes 12.6.20 freezes and shows nothing constantly on Macbook

Tags: itunes, performance

Hundred of people have the same issues and reported on the Apple forum, one example [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7941055).

### What I tried

1. Reinstall iTunes.
2. Set up [Keychain Access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14787/98553)
3. Create a new [iTunes library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104725/98553)

But none works.
Is there any solution?

Comment: What model of Macbook? What macOS version?

Comment: OSX 10.9.5, Macbook Pro 2014

Comment: Sorry, 10.9 is too old for me to remember. Can't you get the Mac up to at least El Capitan? You could also try the 'corporate' version which still contains the App Store, currently at 12.6.5, from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, but does 12.6.5 work? Because I also tried.

Comment: Apparently 12.6.2 was the last to support OS X 10.9 but I've nothing to test on. My oldest Mac is on El Capitan, where it works perfectly - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iTunes#Version_history